# How to send transaction with ethereumjs-tx?

Tags: transactions, ethereumjs

I installed and used ethereumjs-tx, as explained [here](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-tx).

I ran the following commands:

```
var Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx')
var privateKey = new Buffer('xxxxxxxxx', 'hex')

var rawTx = {
  nonce: '0x00',
  gasPrice: '0x09184e72a000', 
  gasLimit: '0x2710',
  to: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000', 
  value: '0x00', 
  data: '0x7f7465737432000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000600057'
}

var tx = new Tx(rawTx)
tx.sign(privateKey)

var serializedTx = tx.serialize()
```

Now, how do I broadcast this transaction to the testnet?

If relevant, I have a geth node running and synced, with an etherbase. Do I need to somehow use geth to send this transaction, or can I send it just with ethereumjs libraries, and (in either way) how can I do it?

Thanks for any help,

Answer (score 6):

Here's an example on how to do it from the web3 documentation:

```
var Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx');
var privateKey = new Buffer('xxxxxxxxxxx', 'hex')

var rawTx = {
  nonce: '0x00',
  gasPrice: '0x09184e72a000', 
  gasLimit: '0x2710',
  to: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000', 
  value: '0x00', 
  data: '0x7f7465737432000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000600057'
}

var tx = new Tx(rawTx);
tx.sign(privateKey);

var serializedTx = tx.serialize();

//console.log(serializedTx.toString('hex'));
//0xf889808609184e72a00082271094000000000000000000000000000000000000000080a47f74657374320000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006000571ca08a8bbf888cfa37bbf0bb965423625641fc956967b81d12e23709cead01446075a01ce999b56a8a88504be365442ea61239198e23d1fce7d00fcfc5cd3b44b7215f

web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(serializedTx.toString('hex'), function(err, hash) {
  if (!err)
    console.log(hash); // "0x7f9fade1c0d57a7af66ab4ead79fade1c0d57a7af66ab4ead7c2c2eb7b11a91385"
});
```

**[SOURCE](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendrawtransaction)**

Answer (score 4):

I believe that you are looking for this:

https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#example-45

check it once.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using JSON-PRC and web3:

- [web3.eth.sendRawTransaction](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendrawtransaction) (takes hex payload as input)

If you need to use a public API service (e.g. Etherscan) it proxyes raw send

- https://github.com/TokenMarketNet/ethereum-smart-contract-transaction-demo/blob/master/src/etherscan.js#L94
- [Full example tutorial](https://tokenmarket.net/blog/creating-ethereum-smart-contract-transactions-in-client-side-javascript/)