# Using json RPC without any libraries besides js

Tags: rpc, sendrawtransaction

I am currently trying to call a function on my smart contract `function adopt(uint petId) public returns (uint)` that has already been deployed to the ropsten network...

but here's the catch. I'm trying to call and sign this contract using the json rpc call `eth_sendRawTransaction()` and I have to do this without any additional libraries besides js like ethereumjs-tx or web3js. Would anyone have any idea how to do this with just the json rpc call? Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to do this? You'd have to create the signed and encoded transaction manually which of course is possible but needlessly inconvenient. Libraries exist for a reason.

Comment: I'm currently building my program in a server based medium that does not support library installations yet and am aware I would need to do these manually. Do you know how I would do this by any chance?

Comment: If installing a package is the issue, I'd probably just copy the browserified version of `ethereumjs-tx`: https://github.com/ethereumjs/browser-builds
Then, see https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10291/how-to-send-transaction-with-ethereumjs-tx

Comment: I'm sorry if i'm being a little unclear, but I'm working in a very limited environment that prevents me from using any minified or browserfied versions. That's one of the main reasons why I'm doing rpc requests. I just want to know, if anyone could help, how to manually interact and sign a transaction using eth_sendRawTransaction(). I've read a lot of stuff online, but I'm still unsure how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

In order to call a function in a contract you need to encode the function name and parameters following [Solidity ABI specification](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/abi-spec.html).

If you want to do that for any functions and parameters it can be quite complex and using an existing library is easier.

But implementing a subset for a known contract should be doable.

Comment: would you know how to sign and send a transaction using RPC calls? I've already looked at the json rpc documentation, but it seems very unclear how to properly send a transaction and signing it.

Comment: Doing generic calls without a library it is not worth the effort IMHO. I'd first prepare "templates" of the JSON RPC using some placeholders using libraries like in here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/3955. Now I'd use this "templates" replacing the placeholders with the real data. For transaction you can follow a similar approach, but the problem you will face is you need to sign the transaction and you really need a library for that.